# Adding a lot of items to WPF Datagrid consumes lots of CPU time

Tags: c#, data-binding, wpfdatagrid, inotifycollectionchanged

I am creating application that has some simple sniffer functionality and which shows the user dumped packets. Packets are read from dump file, which is updated in real time with current traffic and then captured packets are added to Datagrid (each packet is new row). I use data binding to get packets from dump reader, which implements ICollectionChanged interface, so Datagrid is informed on every new packet. Datagrid uses virtualization and deferred scrolling. Almost everything works fine - only exception is huge CPU consumption. This CPU utilization is caused by that I read all new packets (thousands per second), format them for display and for every packet rise CollectionChanged event, which updates Datagrid. Requirement for software is that user doesn't have to see all new packets in real time - they appear dozens of thousands per second, so nobody would notice them all. User has only a view to some packets and when he wants, he may scroll bar down / up to appropriate position to see packets he wants and only in that situation packets must be read from file.

**The problem is** I want Datagrid to update every second to show that new packets arrived, preferably by scaling scroll bar to actual number of packets, but without the need to read them continuosly, format and call CollectionChanged, because it takes CPU time and in addition user wouldn't see new packets if he doesn't scroll the bar. I am informed the number of packets that are arriving so I know all packets' count.

I tried to add fake packets (thereby avoiding reading  and formatting every new packet) only to force Datagrid to scale to actual packets count. It almost worked, because CPU usage fall down and packets where read only when I scrolled bar. But after a moment, when new packets were added to Datagrid, rows in current view started randomly duplicate, i.e.
in first moment packet in the view were displayed 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th, 6th and so on, but after a while they were displayed 1st, 2nd, 3rd, and again 1st, 2nd, 3rd.

I also tried to refresh binding - it worked, but consumed more resources than in first approach so i abandoned it. I also tried to refresh Datagrid's listcollectionview - same effect like in refreshing binding.

Next thing is that when I wanted to add list of packets in one call to CollectionChanged

```
NotifyCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, list));
```

I got error that Range actions are not supported, thrown by     PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.ListCollectionView.ValidateCollectionChangedEventArgs(System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)

So I had to call CollectionChanged for every packet in list of packets, which also increased CPU usage.

**To sum up**, I'd like to inform Datagrid that there are new packets/rows, so Datagrid scroll bar will scale to total number of packets, but packets will be read from file only when user scrolls bar.

I would be very thankful for every suggestion how to resolve my problem.

I've just realized, that there's one important thing to mention and sorry i forgot to tell about it on beginning. My ObservableCollection supports some kind of data virtualization, where in memory I hold only a few necessary packets. When **new packets arrive, I just inform my collection about number of new packets and I don't have to call Add method of collection, because I actually don't add any packet to it - so no packets are acctually read**. Collection has information about total number of packets in that moment and only small amount of them actually held in memory so that grid can display them. Packets are read on the fly only when necessary and when they're not displayed, they are freed. 
But to inform grid about new packets I must (I don't know how to do it another, better way) call CollectionChanged and in argument of this call I need to supply every new packet. And this call to CollectionChanged makes packets are actually read, what consumes CPU. **I want to rescale grid so that scroll bar size would inform new packets arrived, but without necessity for reading packets and calling CollectionChanged one every new packet (which may happen thousand time per second)**. I want packets to be read only when scroll bar position changes, so expensive operations of processing each packet would be done only for few currently visible packets, not for every packet.

Answer (score 0):

If you DataGrid is bound to a ObservableCollection. And each T contains the information about a given packet, the trick will be to make the "T" class instantiation very fast.

Right now it sounds like you are creating each T and calculating all the information needed for display as you are adding them to the collection.

It should take in it's constructor only enough information so that it can retrieve the information about the packet later when the user scrolls the grid to view its row.

Comment: Thanks for answer. My underlying collection receives data only when scroll bar is scrolled. But the problem is that I want the scroll bar size reflect the number of packets, so I must (maybe not must, but I don't know how do it another way) read and add every new packet to Datagrid - and then all calculations happen. I would like to avoid it. I tried add empty packets to grid(without any calculations), which only goal was to reserve space.I did that, because actual packets reading and displaying happened after scrolling bar by user.It almost worked, but packets started to randomly move on grid